# How to print the value of a variable in span tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp-tags

So in this part of the code which is a .jsp file:

```
if($('accountAddress-table-title').length == 0) 
{
                console.log("Adding title accountAddress-table-title");
                var spanAccountAddressTableTitle = $("<span id='accountAddress-table-title' style='font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold;margin-left: 10px;'>Opportunity Account </span>");
                $('#accountAddress-table_filter').before(spanAccountAddressTableTitle);
}
```

I'm trying to print the value stored in variable accountOracleId :

```
var accountOracleId = $(this).data( 'account-oracleid' );

if(addressId != null && addressId.length > 0) 
{
     $('#btnAddres-label').html("Modify Address of Account ("+accountOracleId+")");
} else {
                     $('#btnAddres-label').html("Create Address");
       }
```

Please help me printing the value of accountOracleId next to Opportunity Account .

The resulting output should look like:

```
Opportunity Account (accountOracleId)
```

Comment: if it's a span - change `.html` to `.text` as you're only really changing .. the text .. also console.log it to see if it actually returns a value

Comment: Could you be give an illustration of what you said ..I'd appreciate that

Comment: sure man :) I'll do me best

Comment: thanks :) I'll wait for ya reply.

Comment: Just a note, your Opportunity Account span has `id='accountAddress-table-title'` but later you are using `$('#btnAddres-label').html`. Isn't the `id` different. I can't see any element with `id` as `btnAddres-label`. You need to use `$('#accountAddress-table-title').html(` instead

Comment: I'm showing the part of code from where i need to fetch the value of variable   accountOracleId ..but it looks like the issue is of data tag...Anyways thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign any text/html to a DOM element you need to first target it with a selector:

`$('#idOfElement')` or `$('.classOfElement')` is used - `#` for id and `.` for class.

to assign text/html to a DOM element you'll either need `.text()` to change the text or `.html()` to change the html.

All together it looks like:

`$('#id').text('some text');`

in your case however it might just be that `$(this).data('account-oracleid')` is null. To view the contents of the variable you can use `console.log` which logs to your browser console (accessed via the developer tools under the console tab - F12 on Firefox).

So your full script for the time being should look similar to:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
console.log(id);

$('#mySpan').text('some Text'+ id);
```

if console.log returns a null value, then the issue lies with your data tag and not your code.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with the data tag

Comment: @ShubhamMishra ah no worries :) I did think your code should work to be honest, get the data-tag sorted and your code should just work :)

Comment: @ShubhamMishra no worries, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery

```
$('#id_name/.class_name').html(value_to_insert);
```